# Unable to deposit ether inside contract using receive function

Tags: solidity, ether, payable, fallback-function, receive

Code is :

```
contract sendEther{
    //to send ether, we need to deposit some ether first in this contract
    //We can do it by declaring constructor as payable which enables us to deposit some ether shile deploying
    //OR we can declare a receive/fallback function to receive some ether after the contract is deployed
    //mainly we will use receive func coz we want to just receive ether
    //since we do not have a fallback func, any function called apart from sending ether will fail

    //constructor() payable {}

    receive() external payable {}

    function sendviaTransfer(address payable _to) external payable{
        _to.transfer(123); 
        
    }

    function sendviaSend(address payable _to) external payable{
        bool sent = _to.send(123);

        require(sent, "failed");
    }

    function sendviaCall(address payable _to) external payable{
        (bool sent, ) = _to.call{value : 123}(""); //will forward all available gas with 123 eth to execute this transaction
        require(sent, "failed");

    }
}
```

If I do not use constructor payable and only use receive payable then im unable to deposit ether and sendViaX functions fail.... Plz suggest a solution

I have picked this up from this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlPc3EW-nNA&list=PLO5VPQH6OWdVQwpQfw9rZ67O6Pjfo6q-p&index=39

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what way are you trying to send ethers?

once the contract is deployed you should be able to set the value in remix

[image]

and then click on the button transact, this should work, the contract should be able to receive the ethers because of the receive function

[image]

Comment: Yes .... i figured it out somehow, this was exactly how i wanted to do it .... Thnku for answering :)